# Vue component not binding style

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Hi I'm new at Vue so maybe I am missing something obvious.
I have a component `SliderItem` which I want to set top position so I add a property to data:

```
data () {
    return {
    /*more data*/
     topSliderText: '120px'
    }
}
```

This is the Vue instance

```
import { Slider } from 'vue-easy-slider'
var SliderItem = require('./components/easy-slider-item.vue');

new Vue( {
  el: '#slider',
  data () {
    return {
      list: [
        { background: "url('/images/sliders/be.png')", width: '100%', height: '100%' },
      ]
    }
  },
  components: {
    Slider,
    SliderItem
    },
    mounted() {

    }
} );
```

and then in the view

```
<div class="" id="slider">
<slider animation="fade">
  <slider-item v-bind:style="{top: topSliderText}" v-for="(i, index) in list" :key="index">
    <div :style="i">
        <div class="slider-text">
             <p style="font-size: 5rem; text-align: center;">Page @{{ index +1 }}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
  </slider-item>
</slider>
```

But is not working, the `SliderItem` has no style, and I get this warn on console

> vue-slider.js:561 [Vue warn]: Property or method "topSliderText" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
>
> vue-slider.js:562 [Vue warn]: The computed property "topSliderText" is already defined in data

But when I use Vue chrome extension to see the component, it has the property so... I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You defined `topSliderText` in `SliderItem` component but using it in the parent of `SliderItem`, that is why you get the warn . Define `topSliderText` in the parent itself

Comment: @VamsiKrishna thank you very much! It works :)

Comment: shall i add an answer?

Comment: yes of course!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the `topSliderText` in `SliderItem` component but making use of it in the Parent Component.

That is the reason you get vue [warn] as vue searches for `topSliderText` in the parent component's properties.

So define `topSliderText` as a data property in  the parent component itself